# Reading whole url from servlet

Tags: java, url, servlets

I would like to read from a servlet the exact URL that was set in the HTTP request. That is together with any URL rewritten parts (`;jsessionid=`…).

Is it possible?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url

Comment: No this doesn't include a ";jsession..." part

Comment: Probably the jsessionid parameter was not present in the request URL. If cookies are enabled, the jsessionid will be present as an HTTP header. In this case, you can get it with: request.getRequestedSessionId()

Answer (score 2):

You can get the request URL (the part before `;` and `?`) as follows:

```
StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
```

You can check as follows if the session ID was attached as URL path fragment:

```
if (request.isRequestedSessionIdFromURL()) {
    requestURL.append(";jsessionid=").append(request.getSession().getId());
}
```

You can get and append the query string as follows, if any:

```
if (request.getQueryString() != null) {
    requestURL.append('?').append(request.getQueryString());
}
```

Finally, get the full URL as follows:

```
String fullURL = requestURL.toString();
```

Comment: +1 for the `;jsessionid=` part but you missed a `)` when appending the query string ;)

Comment: uff, wrong, this will not work if servlet receives a url containing invalid sessionid. I do not want to be rude but this is not a complete answer, so I am unaccepting it.

Comment: Ok. What does the `request.getRequestedSessionId()` in such case say? And if it returns the desired value, what does the `request.isRequestedSessionIdFromURL()` and `...FromCookie()` say?

Comment: fromCookie returns true, FromURL returns false and I do not know if URL originaly containtained the ;jsessionid