# How to get the ? at the end of URL when there are no query parameters

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to get the complete URL from HttpServletRequest object. I got various ways of doing it. One of the way is to combine the requestURL with queryString. My situation is that there is a ? at the end with no query params. How do I identify that my URL has a ? at the end.

The URL is something like : http://www.xyz.com/path/id?

I need to consider ? as part of the id. (Client requirement :))

The code I am trying is:

```
public static String getFullURL(HttpServletRequest request) {
StringBuffer requestURL = request.getRequestURL();
String queryString = request.getQueryString();

if (queryString == null) {
    return requestURL.toString();
} else {
    return requestURL.append('?').append(queryString).toString();
}
}
```

Comment: y u are passing ? at the end

Comment: Show the code you have tried.

Comment: I have edited my question to reflect the requirement. It's a client thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url

Comment: How do I identify that my URL has a ? at the end.  `if (requestUrl.toString().endsWith("?"))`

Comment: Why? If there are no query parameters a trailing ? is meaningless. Any element in the system between you and the client is entitled to remove it.

Comment: I understand that it is not required to achieve any functionality. I also know it is a strange requirement. But there should be a way of getting to know the exact URL passed. If there is any, please share.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it will not add extra ? at end if return queryString is null or empty.

```
if (queryString != null && !queryString.trim().equals("")) {
  return requestURL.append('?').append(queryString).toString();    
} else {
  return requestURL.toString();    
}
```

How do I identify that my URL has a ? at the end.
For this you can check

```
 if (queryString == null || queryString.trim().equals("")) {
   In this case just check requestUrl last char. //String data = requestUrl.substring(0, requestUrl.length-1);
   check data has "?"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the difference you are looking for is this:

When a url does not have a question mark, the `request.getQueryString()` result will be `null`.

When a url ends with a question mark but has no query string, the `request.getQueryString()` result will be an empty string or `""`.

So, you should be able to check like this:

```
String queryString = request.getQueryString();
if (queryString == null) {
    // There was no question mark. React accordingly.
} else if ("".equals(queryString)) {
    // The URL ended with a question mark and had no query parameters. React accordingly.
} else {
    // The URL ended with a question mark AND parameters. React accordingly.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it didn't work out. I am using Apache Tomcat 6.0.29

Comment: Interesting. I tested this on JDK 7 and Tomcat 7, so yeah maybe it doesn't work with 6. Sorry about that.