# Getting full url for new url creation

Tags: url, request

Im creating an email and the email has a url link in it.  I want to get the whole url and context so I can redirect the user to where I wish.  Right now my code looks like this

```
String baseURL = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName()
            + request.getContextPath().concat(content);
```

is there a way to simplify this and get the same info?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean something like this:

- getRequestURL() - url without get-parameters
- getQueryString() - get-parameters

  ```
  @Override
  public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) 
  throws ServletException, IOException {
     ((HttpServletRequest)req).getRequestURL();
     ((HttpServletRequest)req).getQueryString();
  }
  ```

see also: [HttpServletRequest to complete URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url)