# Getting Apache Tomcat server path and port dynamically

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I have developed an **API** in **Eclipse** deployed on **Apache Tomcat Server** which modifies an **XML** file kept in the **ROOT** folder of the server.

Apache Tomcat is installed in the D drive in my system and hence I've hard-coded that path in the API like this

```
new File("D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software Foundation\\Tomcat 7.0\\webapps\\ROOT\\example\\example.xml")
```

Also I've configured the server to use **port 8080** hence I've also hard-coded the URI path in the API like this

```
String uriPath = "http://localhost:8080/example/example2";
```

And it works fine.

But now I want to deploy the same API in the form of a **WAR** file on **different** systems having Apache Tomcat.

How do I obtain the Apache Tomcat **ROOT folder path** and the **port number** for those systems programmatically so that one API works for all systems? How do I integrate that into the API?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of reasons within the JEE specification that state why you shouldn't do this but, that aside, you can get a platform agnostic way of determining the tomcat location.

The system defines two variables on startup, CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE.  You should be able to get CATALINA_BASE from the system using System.getProperty("catalina.base")

From there you could hypothetically build up a path like this:

```
final String catalinaBase= System.getProperty("catalina.base");
final File catalinaBaseDir= new File(catalinaBase);
final File exampleXML= new File(catalinaBase, "webapps/root/example/example.xml");
```

As for the URI path, [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url) should provide you with enough reference to do what you want.