# How to get the full url from HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, servlets

Ok, i have these codes:

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
String requestQueryString = httpRequest.getQueryString();
System.out.println(requestQueryString);
```

When open the url "`http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997?_escaped_fragment_=home`",

it printed out:

```
 gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997?_escaped_fragment_=home
```

That url is missing the `http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyProject.html?` part.

How to fix it?

Comment: Read the javadoc of HttpServletRequest. It's all in there.

Comment: it doesn't have getFullURL, & we have to construct separate part, but I looking for 1 line of code that can do the job

Comment: Check this post this question apppears to be a duplicate ,.. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be

```
httpRequest.getRequestURL() + "?" + httpRequest.getQueryString()
```

prints

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/MyProject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997?_escaped_fragment_=home
```

Comment: if the url is "xcd.com#!br" then will your code work ok?

Comment: @tum The `#...` is not something that should be sent in a request. It's for use in the client only.

Comment: Fragments are not sent in HTTP headers: http://blog.httpwatch.com/2011/03/01/6-things-you-should-know-about-fragment-urls/