# Spring RequestMapping: Get path with slashes

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there a way to get the first part of the url path, before /c:

Thats it: **/Category1/Subcategory1.1/Subcategory1.1.1**/c/{categoryCode:.*}

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/**/c")
public class CategoryPageController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{categoryCode:.*}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView viewCategory(@PathVariable String categoryCode,            
            final HttpServletRequest request) {
        String categoryPath = ...
```

I tried to use AntPathMatcher (extractPathWithinPattern) but I'm not able to define the correct pattern.

Answer (score 0):

[inject the request object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504258/spring-3-mvc-accessing-httprequest-from-controller) by simply adding the the HttpServletRequest to the method signature, and
[then access the Request Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url)  by calling getRequestURL().

(oh and auto converting answers to comments, stackoverflow jumps the shark)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I've jet injected HttpServletRequest, but colling getRequestURL() i retrieve the full path (http:// ....)  i don't need it, I need just the part before "/c/" for exemple: /Category1/Subcategory1.1/Subcategory1.1.1/ 
Regards