# Relations among the methods to access parts of URL in HttpServletRequest object

Tags: java, servlets, request

On the `HttpServletRequest` object, assuming that the calling URL is not encoded, can assume that:

`getContextPath()+getServletPath()+getPathInfo()==getRequestURI()` is always true?

I'm pretty sure the answer is yes but the `getRequestURI` is somehow obscure in describing what it exactly is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpServletRequest to complete URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url)

Comment: Is a different question because I am trying to figure out what the exact parts of the getRequestUri. I know that getRequestUri doesn't include the parameters and start after the protocol, but is it exactly comprised of the other three function calls?