# How to convert HttpServletRequest to raw request string?

Tags: java

I need to convert **HttpServletRequest** to raw http request string like:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
```

I know I could concat headers and body, but is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url

Comment: I think the most information you can obtain is to get the URL from the `HttpServletRequest` and then extract the pieces you want.

Comment: I don't want to extract info, I want to convert parsed request back into raw request string.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: @EJP I need to forward this request to somewhere else.

Comment: But not verbatim. If you're trying to write an HTTP proxy you're going about it entirely the wrong way.

Comment: @EJP actually, I'm trying to tunnel internal http server using spring web socket.