# How to retrieve current URL with Springboot (HttpServletRequest request) While using a button

Tags: java, servlets, spring-boot, request-mapping

I have a website on which I added a dropdown menu and a button. When the dropdown menu changes it calls a Requestmapping "/Filter".

The following code is underlying the Requestmapping "/Filter"

```
@Controller
public class FilterController
{

@RequestMapping(value = "/Filter")
public String selectmenu(@RequestParam String selectmenu, HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println(selectmenu);

    String URL = makeUrl(request);
    System.out.println(URL);

    return “ABC";
};

public static String makeUrl(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    return request.getRequestURL().toString() + "?" + request.getQueryString();
}
}
```

This returns the following URL: `http://localhost:8080/Filter?null`

I understand why this URL is returned. But the URL in the address bar is different, namely:  `http://localhost:8080/Name?id=1`

I want to retrieve the URL in the address bar, how can this be accomplished?

Comment: I'm sorry for posting. When I searched i couldn't find the answers. When i posted this post The third related post gave the answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpServletRequest to complete URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url)