# Convert HttpServletRequest to cURL command for Postman

Tags: java, tomcat, curl, postman

I am debugging my application and I want to catch the request (*HttpServletRequest*) as curl command so that I can import that to postman and try it with different options.

The problem that I have is that it has lots of dynamically added headers and it's rather difficult to write that manually in postman.

I found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222238/httpservletrequest-to-complete-url), but it only helps getting URL without headers and it's impossible to import the result in postman.

Comment: Can you modify your code or does this have to be external to Tomcat?

Comment: It's inside library and I suspect it doesn't work correctly. That's one of the reason for me wanting to take the request from it and use it externally

Comment: If you can modify your `web.xml` then you could use something like [this](https://github.com/librucha/servlet-logging-filter).  This will allow you to dump the request and response.  It is a servlet filter so you'll have to be able to add it to `web.xml`.